# $15$ integers $m_1 \ldots m_{15}$such that $ \sum _{k=1} ^{15} m_k \arctan {k} = \arctan 16$

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, contest-math

> Determine whether or not there exist $15$ integers $m_1 \ldots m_{15}$ such that $ \sum _{k=1} ^{15} m_k \cdot  \arctan (k) = \arctan (16)$.

This is a question from IMC 2015 Day 1 Problem. [Here](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2015/imc2015-day1-solutions.pdf) is the link for the solution.

Their solution goes like this.

Suppose that the equation is satisfied by some integers $ m_1, \ldots ,m_{15}$. Then the argument of the complex number $ z_1 = 1+16i$ coincides with the argument of $$z_2 = (1+i)^{m_1} (1+2i)^{m_2} \cdots \cdots (1+15i)^{m_{15}}$$

Therefore the ratio $R=z_1/z_2$ is real and nonzero.**As $Re(z_1)=1$ and $Re(z_2)$ is an integer, $R$ is an integer.**  So we get $$(1+16^2)R^2=\prod ^{15} _{k=1} (1+k^2)^{m_k} $$. Since $1+16^2=257$ is prime, which yields an easy contradiction through $p$-adic valuations.

My thought is that if one of $m_i$'s is negative then $Re(z_2)$ is not necessarily integer. On the other hand all of $m_i$'s cant be positive since $ \arctan 1 + \arctan 2 > \arctan 16$.

Whats the solution to the problem?

Comment: @RossMillikan It was a typo. Edited. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the published solution is inaccurate. But it suffices that the number $R$ is rational. We need only that the exponent of $257$ in $R^2$ is even.

Another possible fix is replacing $(1+ji)^{m_j}$ by $(1+(\mathrm{sgn}\, m_j)ji)^{|m_j|}$.